# Approximation by a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism on the cicle

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be a diffeomorphism on the circle $\mathbb{T}$, where $f$ is in the $C^1$ topology and has a fixed point. It is asked to prove that $f$ can be approximated by a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism by using Sard's theorem.